# Android chrome custom tab customizable

Tags: android, css, chrome-custom-tabs

in how far is the chrome custom tab customizable? We are programming a app which is loading a webview in a fragment with an own header (action bar) and footer. Is custom tab loading in full screen or is their any way to load a chrome custom tab with a margin or something like that?
To change the action bar title or color is not enough for our plan.

Also i want to know about a way to display css3 properly in android versions without chromium (above android version 4.4 as far as i know).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Custom Tabs Activity takes the whole screen, but it's is possible to customize the Toolbar (header) and, on most recent versions, to add a Bottom Toolbar (footer).

Here's a list of customizations possible with Custom Tabs:

- Custom Toolbar color
- Adding an Action button to the Toolbar
- Adding Menu Items to the overflow menu
- Custom Back button icon
- Custom start/exit animations

In the version 23.2.0 of the Custom Tabs support library, the following customizations have been added:

- Adding up to 5 Action buttons to a bottom toolbar
- Custom color for the bottom toolbar
- Adding a default Share action to the overflow menu.

There are samples on how to implement each of those customizations on the [Github Demo](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/demos/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsdemos/CustomUIActivity.java)

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to dynamically change the toolbar color after the Custom Tab builder has been created. This has been an issue for over 6 years now; see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37083468

Comment: note: the linked issue is about having more control over the icon colors and tint of the status bar at launch and not about dynamically changing the color after the Custom Tab is launched.